# Hibernate multitenancy test fails with NPE

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, hibernate-4.x, multi-tenant

I'm using schema based multi-tenancy providing implementations for both MultiTenantConnectionProvider & CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver. Trying to get a hibernate session for a single tenant fails with an NPE.
Looking into hibernate's source code, it seems that JDBCServicesImpl initializes the connectionProvider to null in the else block

```
private JdbcConnectionAccess buildJdbcConnectionAccess(Map configValues) {
    final MultiTenancyStrategy multiTenancyStrategy = MultiTenancyStrategy.determineMultiTenancyStrategy( configValues );

    if ( MultiTenancyStrategy.NONE == multiTenancyStrategy ) {
        connectionProvider = serviceRegistry.getService( ConnectionProvider.class );
        return new ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess( connectionProvider );
    }
    else {
        connectionProvider = null;
        final MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider = serviceRegistry.getService( MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class );
        return new MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess( multiTenantConnectionProvider );
    }
}
```

Please find the test case for this here - http://pastebin.com/7Mt9wtHt and its stacktrace - http://pastebin.com/8ygAu7eh

Is there something basic I am missing out?

Comment: Hi, can you post the error stacktrace? I want to check where you got the NPE.

Comment: Sure, I have attached it as another pastebin to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after looking at the source code for awhile now. Hibernate (as for now) does not support schema export. this is taken from their [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

> Currently schema export will not really work with multi-tenancy. That may not change

So, in your case, the fix would be to remove this line

```
config.getProperties().put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "validate");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. When I googled, there is a bug posted for this in hibernate.
Here is the link https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7395